# привязка и отвязка array object (openGL)

Tags: c++, opengl

Изучал код ,рисующий треугольник(с известного learnopengl) меня интересует вот такой момент

```
GLuint VBO, VAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
```

где verticles-массив вершин треугольника

Сие действо происходит вне игрового цикла, потом мы анбиндим VAO c помощью

```
glBindVertexArray(0)
```

В игровом же цикле мы снова вызываем эту функцию,и снова отвязываемся

```
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Зачем тогда нужно вообще объявление VAO,если по-идее нам достаточно массива с вершинами и выделенного под него буфера?По-сути в коде VAO используется только в вызовах glBindVertexArray,никакой информации туда мы не передаем.В описании указано,что VAO хранит вершинные атрибуты,но как они туда передаются,если я нигде в явном виде этого не делаю?Что вообще значит эта привязка VAO?Когда мы биндим ноль, данные из VAO никуда не деваются?

Comment: [Там же это все расписано](https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Hello-Triangle), даже диаграммы что где хранится есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Что вообще значит эта привязка VAO?

В целях экономии ресурсов, OpenGL работает как конечный автомат, поэтому контекст передаётся не в виде аргументов функций, но его нужно определять заранее. В данном случае, одни функции привязывают VAO или VBO как текущие, а другие (например, `glDrawArrays` или `glBufferData`) их используют.

---

> В описании указано,что VAO хранит вершинные атрибуты, но как они туда передаются, если я нигде в явном виде этого не делаю?

В Вашем коде данные передаются в текущий VBO функцией `glBufferData` из аргумента `vertices`, который затем привязывается к текущему VAO функцией `glVertexAttribPointer`.

Кстати, так как VAO лишь *ссылается* на VBO, один и тот же VBO может использоваться в нескольких VAO. [Пример](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/4625).

---

> Зачем тогда нужно вообще объявление VAO, если по-идее нам достаточно массива с вершинами и выделенного под него буфера?

Действительно, в простых случаях как этот такие понятия вроде VAO, VBO не обязательны, и в прошлом их не было: сведения о координатах и цветах каждой вершины передавались отдельными вызовами функций. Однако, потребности и технологии развиваются, нужно обрабатывать всё больше данных более хитроумными способами: одни массивы определяют положение вершин, другие их текстурные координаты, третьи их нормали, четвёртые описывают последовательности индексов этих вершин, и т.д.

Поэтому для упрощения работы с многочисленными параметрами вершин, они передаются целыми массивами, что значительно быстрее, чем передача данных для каждой вершины независимо. Объекты VBO и VAO используются как раз для этого — абстрагируют работу с массивами данных о вершинах. В итоге, они могут отрисовываться сложной / заданной последовательностью с помощью функции `glDrawElements`, а также могут применяться с любым назначением и в любых количествах в шейдерах разных видов.

Comment: Как связаны `glBufferData` и `VAO`?) Это же забота `VBO`. Задача `VAO` тут - хранить правильную информацию о том, как эти `VBO` использовать, т.е. - `glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);`

Comment: @selya действительно, возникла некоторая неточность в словах. Спасибо, поправил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно (но не надо)

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glColor3f(0.5,0,0);
glVertex2f(300.0,210.0);
glVertex2f(340.0,215.0);
glVertex2f(320.0,250.0);
glEnd();
```

VAO и VBO позволяют использовать ресурсы видеокарты более быстрым способом. VAO хранит в себе VBO's и таким образом мы можем брать с него только то что нужно